# Can binary data be stored in Redis Hashes without base64? (via phpredis)

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

The official website said that Strings are binary safe, but it did not mention other types. So...

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: @arkascha I have tried, it works for me. Just don't know if there will be special cases.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes):

> Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values.

Since strings are binary-safe, hashes are as well.